# how to send email from web page in the most simple way with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my web site I have "contuct us" page and I want the manager able to reply via email
to the customers.
All the process need to be in the server side.
It is important to note that I works with Webmatrix development environment...

So considering my web development what is the simple way for me to add the ability to 
send email?

My HTML code is:

```
foreach(var row in db.Query(displayApplicant,nameOfcustomer))
                {
                <tr>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.messegeID</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.name</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.email</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.isCustomer</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.userID</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen">@row.content</td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen"><a href="#" onclick="answerBox('@row.messegeID','@row.userID')" style="color: #b04e4e">answer the question</a></td>
                    <td class="dispExpertActScreen"><a href="#" onclick="reqeustToDelete('@row.messegeID')" style="color: #b04e4e">remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                }
```

the javascript function: (to save details in hidden fields)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function answerBox(messegeID,userID) {
        var msg = prompt('answer to customer:');
        document.getElementById('answer').value = msg;
        document.getElementById('ansMode').value = 'true';
        document.getElementById('msgID').value = messegeID;
        document.getElementById('user').value = userID;
        document.getElementById('ansMessege').submit();
    }

</script>
```

the hidden fields:

```
<form method="post" id="ansMessege" style="font-size: medium; margin-top: 10%" dir="rtl">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="msgID" id="msgID" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ansMode" id="ansMode" value="">
</form>
```

the asp.net code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>

@{
    Layout = "~/_ManagerLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Management Applications";

 }
@{
    var db = Database.Open("MyProjectSite");
    var display="no";
    var displayApplicant="";
    var nameOfcustomer="";
    var category="";
    var yesNo="";
     if(IsPost)
    {
     if(Request.Form["ansMode"] == "true")
          {
              var selectQuery="SELECT * FROM messegesFromCustomers";
              var id=Request.Form["msgID"];
              var msg=Request.Form["answer"];
              var user=Request.Form["user"];

              foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQuery))
              {
                  if(row.messegeID == Convert.ToInt32(id))
                  {
                      if(row.isCustomer == "yes")// **send the messege to customer account**
                      {
                          var insertQuery="UPDATE messegesFromCustomers SET answer=@0 WHERE messegeID=@1";
                          db.Execute(insertQuery,msg,id);
                          Response.Write("<script>alert('your answer sent successfully');</script>");
                          break;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          // **Send messege to Occasional customer via email**
                         // **here I want to add code for sending email...**


                          string from = "ofirhgy@gmail.com";
                          string to = "ofirhgy@gmail.com";
                          string subject = "Hi!";
                          string body = "How are you?";
                          SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.gmail.com";
                          SmtpMail.Send(from, to, subject, body);

                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }

          }

 }



}
```

As you see I try to use WebMail.Send(...) but I don't know how...
In addition to that I saw that someone wrote that there is need to add some code 
to the Web.config or something like that....

thanks you for help.

Edit:I edit the code and I put the line:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
```

in the top of the asp.net page but I get this error:

Parser Error Message: A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character.  Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid at the start of a code block and they must occur immediately following "@" with no space in between.

Can anybody place for me the exact code?

Comment: hay again... can you see my edited code and tell me why there is an error? thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to that

In my code I added this and the email sent sucessfully:

```
 if(isCustomer == "yes")
               {

                  db.Execute(insertQuery,msg,id);
                  db.Execute(deleteQuery,id);
               }

               else
               {
                   WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
                   WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
                   WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;//25
                   WebMail.UserName = "my gmail user name";
                   WebMail.Password = "my gmail password";
                   WebMail.From = "my address of email";
                   // Send email
                   WebMail.Send(
                    to: email,
                    subject: "Message from "some name of site" - Site",
                    body: msg);

                    db.Execute(deleteQuery,id);    

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to import the `System.Web.Mail` namespace:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
```

Sending the message is a matter of calling `SmtpMail.Send()` with the following arguments: `sender`, `recipient`, `subject` and `body`. For example, we'd send an email in C# like this:

```
string from = "sender@example.com";
 string to = "recipient@example.com";
 string subject = "Hi!";
 string body = "How are you?";
 SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.example.com";
 SmtpMail.Send(from, to, subject, body);
```

`SmtpMail.SmtpServer` lets you specify the mail server used to deliver your message.

Content from [here](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How-To-Send-A-Simple-Email-With-Asp-Net.htm)

Comment: where I need to insert this line:<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>

Comment: on the first rules of your ASP page.

Comment: hay again... can you see my edited code and tell me why there is an error? thanks...